# How to insert js file dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load some js file more dynamic so I use a div object with a class name to wrap the checking script. After the checking script check the specific js file is not loaded, it will create a new external js file string to the parent div. However, nothing happened. The following code shows how I check is the js file has been loaded or not and how to insert the script string. But the result is only the `jQuery  is not loaded` is printed in the console.

```
<div class="loadPagejQuery">
    <script>
        if (window.jQuery) {  
            // jQuery is loaded  
            console.log("jQuery is loaded  ");
            } else {
            // jQuery is not loaded
            console.log("jQuery is not loaded  ");
            (function () {
                // Load the script
                var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
                script.src = '/Style/js/jquery-1.10.2.js';
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                document.getElementsByClassName("loadPagejQuery")[0].appendChild(script);
            })();
        }
    </script>
</div>

<script id="the_jquery_ui" src="/Style/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>//Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have to listen `onload` event and then execute your script...

Comment: Attach an `onload` event to the script tag that you have created to load jquery and in that callback function for onload execute the `.ready` function.

Comment: will the external js file string be executed if it is inserted after the checking script?

Comment: @HarshitJain Could you give me more information about your comment so that I can google it?

Comment: @MRWonderFuXker Please refer this [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var script = document.createElement("script");

script.src = '/Style/js/jquery-1.10.2.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
script.onload = function() {
  alert("Script loaded and ready");
  fun();
};

function fun(){ 
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        alert("Try now Working Jquery Library");
    });
}
```

Try to insert the script Head Tag instead of inserting class.
Check the script will be load using onload statement and further try the following statements.

Comment: I have already tried this way. However, after executing your script, the jquery is inserted to the html head! The jQuery-UI will get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error because the jQuery is not exactly  loaded in its executing time.

Comment: Now i made updations to execute a jquery library how to insert and to be load.. Now you will not get "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"...

Comment: do you mean the jQuery-UI file should be loaded in the fun() by JS?

Comment: Yes correct, Which means that jquery statements will be execute using onload statement will be load after only.. Dynamically we are loading, so we have to check successfully file is loaded or not. Using script onload statement.

Comment: i think it is better to assign onload function before append the child